# LaTeX force slash fraction notation

Tags: latex

Is it possible to force latex to use the slash notation for a fraction (i.e., separating the numerator and denominator with a slash instead of stacking them on top of one another)?  Just using a slash (/) instead of \frac looks bad because the slash does not size itself properly.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is a command that might work for you:

```
\newcommand{\slfrac}[2]{\left.#1\middle/#2\right.}
```

It sizes the slash based on the size of the numerator and denominator.

Answer (score 7):

Try the [nicefrac](http://ctan.org/pkg/nicefrac) package

Comment: Thanks for the reply... this is close to what I want, but shrinks large symbols unnecessarily (everything becomes small enough so that the slash looks reasonable).  Occasionally \frac uses the slash even in display mode, and when it does, large symbols stay the same but the slash grows to accommodate them.  Is there a way to force it to always use the slash for a given fraction?